# How can I rotate log files with nestjs-pino?

Tags: nest, pino

I'm developing server with nestjs and I wanna rotate log files with nestjs-pino like `winston-daily-rotate-file`.
I chose `nest-pino` for logger beacause of its simplicity and being much more comfortable than winston.
However, I don't know how to rotate log files with `nest-pino` and cannot find the way.
Does anyone know how to rotate file with `nest-pino`?

I searched the way for very long time but I couldn't find it.
I'm considering using `logrotate` if there isn't package for rotating files with `nest-pino`.
BUT, I want to use package for more simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rotating-file-stream  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotating-file-stream) . This module is fully compatible with pino. For transport of logs to file we have default transport 'pino/file' in pino ,instead we need to use this module.This module will create file and write in that file , so it will watch this file and rotate it. But log rotation has performance overhead with this module. Instead use 'log-rotate' if it meets your use case.

Comment: Cool! I'll try this package. I appreciate for your solution!